# Raspberry Pi: Keyboard input for bash script without connected HDMI display

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, keyboard, systemd, rc

I'm searching for a possibility to control a bash script by keyboard without having a HDMI display connected.

**Background:** I want to build a vfd display that can be controlled by a usual keyboard. For this I connected the display with a raspberry pi. The vfd display will be controlled by the serial interface and this is already working.

**The script:**
Key presses will be recognized by a endless loop and `read -r -N 1 -p "" -d "" _KEY` inside.
The script basically works. When I start the script with HDMI display and mouse connected, I can use the keyboard. When I start the script by SSH, the connected computer can control the script but the raspberry pi connected keyboard is not working.

What I already tried:

| try | issue |
| --- | --- |
| Run script as **systemd** service | Script starts but receives constantly a lot of inputs without pressing a key. The input cannot be interpreted. Key presses will not be recognized. Is there a possibility to recognize the keyboard input in the service configuration? Already tried to configure tty but no tty device for the keyboard is available. |
| Run script in **rc.local / .bashrc** | Script starts but keypresses will not be recognized. This seems not to be a good solution with a endless loop in rc.local, right? |

Output `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05af:8277 Jing-Mold Enterprise Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
...
```

Do you have any idea to control the script with the keyboard? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's nice, but the following solution works for me:

1. Add the script to the .bashrc of user
2. Configure auto login for the user: `sudo raspi-config` -> `1 System Options` -> `S5 Boot / Auto Login` -> Select Option `B2 Console Autologin` -> Select Finish and reboot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the default tty to UART tty is a better way. The step can be:

- Edit the GRUB configuration file at /etc/default/grub hopefully
- Add console=ttyS0 (the UART tty for your vfd)
- run sudo update-grub to apply the changes

Not sure if this work because i dont have an environment around